# How can I tell if Remote Profiles are in use?

Tags: profile, security, form-snippets, snippet

Remote profiles are difficult to configure safely, so they're turned off by default on modern CiviCRM installs.  However, if I have an old CiviCRM installation, how can I tell if this feature is in use before I turn it off?

Comment: Thx Jon - I was just commenting elsewhere that it is a shame that many suggestions and fixes discussed via Chat do not make it in to here.

Answer (score 3):

It's not 100% but you can identify submissions that are local origin by referer in the web logs.

Additionally, any POST that is not from an external form will have a preceding GET for the same form path, while a POST that is a profile submission from remote origin will not. Good opportunity to practice [a little awk](https://gregable.com/2010/09/why-you-should-know-just-little-awk.html)